# Get value of view element in MVC that not relevant to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When I have a DropDownList that relevant to Model of view like this:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Group.Name, selectList)`

I Can retrieve Values in controller as follow:

```
string SelectedGroupName = collection.GetValue("Group.Name").AttemptedValue;
```

But now I have a DropDownList that not relevant to model but I need the value of that, this is my new DropDown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DDName", selectList)
```

How can I retrieve the selected value of that in controller? is there any hiddenfield or other thing to pass value from view to controller?

**Edit**

This is my view:

```
@model PhoneBook.Models.Numbers
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}
<h2>
    Move And Delete</h2>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Label of Numbers</legend>
<div class="display-label">
        Delete Label And Move All Numbers with: @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
 model.Title)</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        To @Html.DropDownList("DDName", selectlist)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Move Numbers And Delete Label" name="MDbtn" />
     </p>
 }
```

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection) {
var result = Request["DDName"];

//Use result

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

but result set to null, why?

Comment: @amit_g : that not work, I Edit question and add some code and test your way, please look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this must be work:

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var dd = collection.GetValue("DDName");
            .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is

**In your view:**

put `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {` above the `<fieldset>`, so the `@Html.DropDownList("DDName", selectlist)` is inside it.

**In your controller:**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection, string DDName) 
{ [...] }
```

And I'm fairly sure MVC3 will automagically give you the selected value as parameter to your controller.

If that does not work, try `object DDName` in your controller instead.

Answer (score 0):

Think the ddl has to be in your form if you want to pass the value in through the form collection

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that your dropdown isn't contained inside the form in your view.

You have to put it after BeginForm:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   <div class="display-field">
     To @Html.DropDownList("DDName", selectlist)
   </div>

   <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Move Numbers And Delete Label" name="MDbtn" />
   </p>
 }
```

Then you have can use FormCollection or a designated parameter. The default Modelbinder will work with both approaches:

```
ActionResult Action (FormCollection collection, string DDName)
```

You can easily check those issues with [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).